# .Net Xml whitespace deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml, whitespace

Just tried to serialize and deserialize several whitespace with additional xml attribute to preserve them as described in [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) (see remarks). Here is simple C# example.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XmlTextTest
{
    [Serializable]
    public class WhitespaceTest
    {
        [XmlAttribute("space", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")]
        public string Space { get; set; } = "preserve";

        [XmlText]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var testValue = "    ";
            var test = new WhitespaceTest { Value = testValue };
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(WhitespaceTest));
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                serializer.Serialize(stream, test);

                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd());

                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var deserialized = serializer.Deserialize(stream) as WhitespaceTest;

                if (deserialized.Value != testValue)
                    throw new Exception();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result xml

```
<WhitespaceTest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xml:space="preserve">    </WhitespaceTest>
```

May be it's my mistake but I expect that whitespaces will be deserialized as is ([according to standard](https://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace)), not "null". How to mark original Type property to prevent replacing whitespaces with "null" into XmlText region.

Modified example to use IgnoreWhiteSpace property:

```
    var str = "<WhitespaceTest xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xml:space='preserve'>    </WhitespaceTest>";
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.IgnoreWhitespace = false;
    var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(str), settings);
    var deserialized2 = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as WhitespaceTest;
    if (deserialized2.Value != testValue)
        throw new Exception();
```

Still no effect.

Updated:

Created implementation of IXmlSerializable and added "xml:space=preserve" attribute manually. See example:

```
    public class Sample : IXmlSerializable
    {
        #region Properties

        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region IXmlSerializable members

        public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
        {
            return null;
        }

        public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
        {
            ReadXml(this, reader);
        }

        public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
        {
            WriteXml(this, writer);
        }

        #endregion IXmlSerializable members

        internal static void ReadXml(ILocalizedMappable serializable, System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
        {
            var node = new XmlDocument().ReadNode(reader);
            if (node != null)
            {
                serializable.Text = node.InnerText;
            }
        }

        internal static void WriteXml(ILocalizedMappable serializable, System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
        {
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xml", "space", string.Empty, "preserve");
            writer.WriteString(serializable.Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it an option to wrap the stream in an XmlReader with XmlReaderSettings with IgnoreWhitespace = false and pass that to the XmlSerializer.Deserialize method?

Comment: @JssDWt Modified example, set IgnoreWhiteSpace to false (see post). Behavior isn't changed.

Comment: Also the same problem. It seems it is impossible to deserialize it correctly. Did you have found any workaround?

Comment: @videokojot I found the only workaround - you should manually add "xml:space=preserve" attribute on serialization (use the IXmlSerializable interface to achieve this). See update in the post.

Comment: @AndreyBurykin Unfortunately I have no control over the generated xml, thus I cannot add the xml:space preserve attribute...